# Where do you turn for code base improvement on a multi-project scale?

Tags: source-code

Are there resources out there for a programmer with a large code base to have professional alalysis performed for the goal of finding the areas of most needed improvement?

Logic/Reason tells me there's a limit to what a code review question can absorb, and also that the amount of work involved is not something that should need be free.

Comment: This is a really odd way to phrase your question. Are you trying to gauge the market potential for starting a business in this space?

Comment: No, i want help with my code base - a result nearly three years of doing my best to get it right but as a one man team. That said, after I wrote the qutestion and it came out that way I had the same thought that you are having - that it might be an interesting business idea.

Comment: Quick follow up on that... the reason I want help isn't that I think my code is low quality, it's more because I have no way of knowing how it stacks up to industry standards/best practices to the extent that they even exist. For example, suppose I used all datasets everywhere - this might alert me to EF as a more modern approach - that's just a simple example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While 5 years old, this article is a great start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896741.aspx

If you want a professional review of your code base, you can find many consulting groups that will do software reviews for you.  Such services tend to not be cheap by any means, but they *can* save you a lot of trouble in the long run by pointing out potential issues that will later cause you extra work or maintenance headaches.

Comment: that was a useful article - kind of addressed exactly my motivation for posting this quesiton

Answer (score 2):

Does any part of your code cause you pain when you see it again or change it? If so, then I suggest you take those portions of your code and research how people have solved the problems you are having with it. If you keep doing this over and over again you'll eventually get better at spotting weak points as you are designing and developing the code. Over time you'll have a dramatically improved code-base that you'll (hopefully) feel better about, regardless of how you feel about it right now.